# Visual Studio Windows Form app is not working

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using `visual studio 2010` , and i am making window form application using `c++` , it work fine until the appearance of `main form` , but when i drag and drop something from toolbar it show me the below error :

[image]

But when i checked i have the following files installed in my system

[image]

it works for me in c# but not in c++

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2010, right-click on your project in the 'Solution Explorer' and click on 'Properties'. On the 'Application tab' in the Properties window check if `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` is the selected 'Target Framework'. If not, select it from the drop-down menu.

If that is fine, then there could be a problem with one of your Project References.

Comment: There is Application tab there , there is a tab name Framework and Refrences , and its written above `targeted framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.0`

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, expand your project, expand 'References' and check if any of the References are showing any errors.

Comment: Sometimes having a long path (more than 256 characters) creates this problem. Keep your path short, meaning don't keep your project too deep inside a folder. For example, keep it in `C:\Project` rather than `C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project\....`