# Drag and drop UI designer in Visual Studio without MFC?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++-2010

I want to write a C++ application using Visual Studio, without using MFC (or Qt). I want to design the user interface (dialog boxes, menu bars, etc.) using drag-and-drop (similar to the Winforms designer in C#).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowsForms is part of the .NET Framework, so you can't use it directly with standard C++. You could use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) a version of the C++ programming language developed by Microsoft to work with the .NET Framework.

Comment: but i got the error here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125703/visual-studio-windows-form-app-is-not-working